# Word for "did or did not accept"

Tags: word-request

When coding, I came over to a comment saying "Determine if the user accepted".

I hope to change into a verb-noun pair, that is "Determine user ???", with the question mark stands for the noun of "did or did not accept". Is there such a word?

Comment: I am confused by your meaning You want a noun or a verb? and do want one or two? How can one word have two opposite meanings?

Comment: @Brad Sorry for the late reply. "Verb-noun pair" here means that "Determine" is the verb part, and "User ???" is the noun part. I really need to improve by describing skills :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Acceptance" is probably what you want: *Determine user acceptance.*

You could also try "determine user *approval*" or the more generic "determine user *response*."

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean approve? or a derivative of it?

---

approve verb (AGREE) to accept, allow, or officially agree to something: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approve)